# Ruby Application Helper Invalid Authenticity Token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Help! My error message is saying : ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken. Is there something wrong with my interpolation of form_authenticity_token?

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
def auth_token
    "<input
        type='hidden'
        name='authenticity_token
        value='#{form_authenticity_token}'
    />".html_safe
end
```

end

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what version of Rails you're using (but let's say it's 4 or 5), all you should need to get the tokens working is:

```rb
# In the html head section of app/views/layouts/application.erb
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

You should *not* need the custom `auth_token` helper method you've created!